# C# application for Multiple user Login on same Site

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, multiple-users

Is this possible to make an application that allows us to make an application that has 4 web browser controls and we can independently use each browser control for different Login on same website.

Lets say i have one web browser dealing with hotmail with Office Email 
where as Second web browser control dealing with hotmail with Personal Email

Currently i have searched that web browser cannot have different PROXIES or USER-Agent Strings.

Any Solutions?

Comment: If you are NOT logging on to the website, but you are logging on to other services (mail), sure it is... Your website can act as a login broker. Why do you need different User-Agent headers or proxies?

Comment: Yes i want it to implement for Services how can it be done.I thought of User agent or proxies to make them different so that mailing website cannot recognize that i have logged in from other user

Comment: Authentication is tied to an auth ticket. Find out how is the ticket sent to the service (cookie, url, form) and apply it to your controls.

Comment: can you give me any clues how to do so

Comment: Url and form auth should work right away without any changes. Maybe setting that you do not accept cookies will force this mode (if the service support automatic auth mode switching).
Otherwise try `webBrowser.Document.Cookie` to change the auth cookies (casting may be required here). You can also try doing web requests manually with `CookieContainer`. The are many ways to do that, you should probably read some pages on authentication.

Comment: @Afnan: I did not expect the comments to turn into an answer :-P. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving my comments as an answer.

Authentication is tied to an auth ticket. Find out how is the ticket sent to the service (cookie, url, form) and apply it to your controls.

URL and form auth should work right away without any changes - I see these used a lot in PHP apps.
Maybe setting that you **do not accept cookies** will force this mode - if the service supports automatic auth mode switching (eg. WebForms with `cookieless="AutoDetect"`).

Otherwise try `webBrowser.Document.Cookie` to change the auth cookies - this works out of the box with WinForms.

You need to cast the Document and add reference to the COM *"Microsoft HTML Object Library"* in WPF:

```
string cookie = (webBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2).cookie;
```

You can also try doing web requests manually with [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) and use the WebBrowser control only for visualization. You should probably read some pages on authentication.

Basically you need to send different cookies to different services.